# How can I replace specific fields of an existing row in php+mysql ?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I replace specific fields of an existing row in php+mysql ?

```
Table
Field1 Field2 Field3
value1 value2 value3
```

I need to find the row with value1 in the table, and replace value3 only (leaving value2 as it is).

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do a simple `UPDATE` statement.

`UPDATE Table SET Field3 = 'NewValue' WHERE Field1 = 'value1'`

Answer (score 1):

the sql query is like (using [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)) :

```
UPDATE Table SET Field3 = 'mynewvalue' where Field1 = 'Value1'
```

to run it in php use

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) or [mysqli::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)